# What is the opposite of "paying in advance"?

Tags: terminology, payment

In a following point of a tenancy agreement my tenant is arguing that he will not pay the rent in advance. He will rather pay Rs:9000 the next month starting from the date of agreement.

That the tenant has agreed to pay Rs.9000/= only as monthly house rent including gas and electricity charges in advance on 12th of each month.

My question is how do I alter the above mentioned point as he needs? I actually want to change the "opposite of advance" in the following statement:

That the tenant has agreed to pay Rs.9000/= only as monthly house rent including gas and electricity charges in "opposite of advance" on 12th of each month.

Comment: In the financial sense "arrears"

Comment: You mean I need to write In arrears???

Comment: is this how you are suggesting me?? "That the tenant has agreed to pay Rs.9000/= only as monthly house rent including gas and electricity charges in arrears on 12th of each month."

Comment: This is a question better directed to a lawyer who is familiar with the laws and standard contract language of wherever it is that you live.  Legal language is a very specialized subset of English.

Comment: "at the end of each rental period"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possibly of use:

[***Arrears***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrears)

> Payment in arrear is a payment made after a service has been provided, as distinct from in advance, which are payments made at the start of a period.
>
> For example, a housing tenant who is obliged to pay rent at the end of each month, is said to pay rent in arrear.

Please note that usually *in arrears* is used for *overdue* payments.

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrears

Comment: "In arrears" is mostly used for overdue payments simply because that is the context in which the concept is most likely to come up. However, that is not in any way implicit in the term itself. For example, mortgage interest is always paid in arrears, but probably most people don't know that or have never thought about it. "In arrears" is the right term for what OP wants to say.

Answer (score -1):

Rent should be paid in accordance with whatever is agreed to by the tenant and the landlord, whether or not there is a *formal* agreement in the form of a written and signed lease. Naturally, the renter would like to pay each month's rent at the end of each month while the landlord would like to receive the rent in advance, i.e. at the beginning of the month. Some leases in the western world specify that each month's rent is due at the beginning of the month with a grace period of one week or ten days: rent paid by the 7th (or by the 10th) is deemed to have been paid in timely fashion while rent payments received later are deemed to be late and there might be a fee for late payment.

- If the OP (landlord) is willing to accept Rs 9000 as the rent (including gas and electricity charges -- bad idea!) for the month at the end of that month (or on the first of the following month), the lease (or agreement) should say so.
- If the landlord is willing to accept the *current* month's rent by the 12th (although he would much rather receive the money on the 1st, i.e. in advance), then the agreement should say so without fussing about the opposite of Advance.
- If the landlord is willing to accept rent for the *past* month by the 12th of the *current* month, then the agreement can say that each month's rent shall be paid by the 12th of the following month again without fussing about the opposite of Advance or using Arrears since, as the answer by Bookeater points out, Arrears usually refers to rent that is paid late, that is, after the agreed-upon due date.